Flutter altering duration on animationcontroller at runtime
I have a functioning animation controller that counts down from a starting time of 4 hours.  I can start the timer, pause the timer and resume the timer again, all of that works fine.
controller = AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 14400),
);

What I am trying to do now is just simply be able to add buttons that for instance "remove 5 minutes from the current remaining time" while the timer is running.
Something that logically, to my mind, looks something like this:
setState(() {
  controller.duration = controller.duration - 300;
});

There doesn't seem to be a way I can find to do this however.   Nothing I am trying seems to be working.  Any ideas?

Oh man, I had honestly spent an hour on this before posting and then the very next thing I tried worked.   For anyone else having this issue, this is what worked:
controller.duration = Duration(seconds: ((controller.duration!.inSeconds * controller.value) - 300).round());

